# Latency with dial?

Tags: twilio

I'm new to Twilio and find documentation etc. to be great, but I can't find a solution to this specific problem.

I have an xml file with

```
<Response>
    <Dial timeout="10" record="record-from-answer" callerId="+caller_id" action="file.php" method="POST">number_to_dial</Dial>
</Response>
```

When the call is placed there's a noticeable lag (delays after speaking). I'm wondering what could be causing this and if there's may be an alternative verb to 'Dial' that we should be using.

**The flow is as follows**:

User calls a Twilio number that has the TwiML (above) associated with it. The call is then routed to a different number and the record-from-answer kicks in.

Twilio client is not used, phone calls are placed from a regular phone.

Thank you

Comment: how are you using this ? Can you describe the full call flow ? Are you calling two numbers and bridging them or are you using Twilio client ?

A full flow will help figure out where does the problem sit

Comment: @am1704 thank you for the comment, just updated the question with the details. I don't think we're using the Twilio client.

Comment: Sounds like a straighforward flow. This is definitely a support question , try mailing this to help@twilio.com